# what is the difference between insert statement with into and without into?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have created table `#temp` with columns `id` as `int identity(1,1)` and `name` as `varchar`.

Say suppose I am writing the following 2 different statements for inserting rows:

```
insert into #temp (name) select ('Vikrant') ;   

insert #temp (name) select ('Vikrant')
```

I want to ask what is the difference between these two types of insert statements?
Is there really any difference in between these insertions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

> [INTO]
>   Is an optional keyword that can be used between INSERT and the target table.

There is no difference between the two statements.

Comment: I am wondering if the same is true for all flavors of SQL, and not just Sql Server (ie Oracle, Sybase, MySQL, etc.)